# Using the option key in Apple Script.

Tags: applescript

I am working on a script that puts in strings of text into a document, and I was wondering how you would have apple script input the keystroke "Option-Return"

Answer (score -1):

keycode 58 + 36

- tell application "System Events" to key code 36 using {option down}

a handy link on applescripty
 - http://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes/